# Jquery Ui slider min and max value range with if/elseif statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to make a simple payday loan calculator using jquery range slides. I have min: $500 and max: $5000 how can I display a statement when a user exceeds $2000 then I display "Only available on repeat customers"

So basically:
A. If loan amount <=2000, No warning message
B. If loan amount between >2000 and <=5000 and period is 3 or 5 months,then display warning message in RED as
i. This loan amount is available to repeat customers only
ii. This period(term) is available to repeat customers only.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
function update() {            
     $interest = 0.3 ;
     $perday = 15 ;
     $amount1 = $("#amount").val();
     $dayscount = $("#days").val();
     $amount2 = parseInt($amount1) + $interest * parseInt($amount1) + (parseInt($dayscount) * ($perday/100));
     $apr = (($amount2-$amount1 / $amount1 ) / ((parseInt($dayscount)/365) * 10000))  ;
     $("#amount2").val($amount2);
     $("#amount3").val(parseFloat($amount2-$amount1).toFixed(2));
     $("#amount4").val($apr);
}
 
debugger;
 
$("#slider1").slider({
    max:5000,
    min:500,
    step:10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
 
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
                update();
       
    }, 
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.value == 2) {
                $("#mindiv").show();
            } else {
                $("#mindiv").hide();
            }
        }
});
 
       
     
function addDaysToDate(days) {
  var mths = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
 
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + (24 * days));
 
  var currD = d.getDate();
  var currM = d.getMonth();
  var currY = d.getFullYear();
 
  return mths[currM] + " " + currD + ", " + currY;
}
 
 
 
$("#slider2").slider({
    max:30,
    min:1,
 
    slide: function(event, ui) {  
 
        $("#days").val(ui.value);
        $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
                update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
    }    
});
 
$("#days").val($("#slider2").slider("value"));
 
$("#days").change(function(event) {
  var data = $("#days").val();
  if (data.length > 0)
  {
     if (parseInt(data) >= 0 && parseInt(data) <= 31)
    {
        $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", data);
     }
     else
     {
        if (parseInt(data) < 1)
       {
           $("#days").val("1");
           $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
       }
       if (parseInt(data) > 31)
        {
            $("#days").val("31");
            $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "31");
        }
     }
  }
  else
  {
    $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
  }
  $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
});
 
update();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Loan Calculator with  two jquery  slider inputs </title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  Loan Amount<div id="slider1"></div>
Your Loan <input type="text" id="amount" value="500"/><br /><br />

hhhh<div id="mindiv">asds</div>
 
Loan Length<div id="slider2"></div>
 
 
Days Loaned <input type="text" id="days" value="1"/><br /><br />
Repayment Date<br />
<div id="date"></div><br />
Your Loan
<input id="amount2" type="text" />
Interest
<input id="amount3" type="text" /><br />
APR
<input id="amount4" type="text" /><br />



  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just quickly, your `ui.value` will never equal `2`. Since the slider min is `500` and max of `5000`, the lowest value would only be 500 and that will always be greater than 2. The div would never be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example code.

```js
$(function() {
  function update() {
    $interest = 0.3;
    $perday = 15;

    $amount1 = parseInt($("#amount").val());
    $dayscount = parseInt($("#days").val());
    $amount2 = $amount1 + $interest * $amount1 + ($dayscount * ($perday / 100));
    $apr = (($amount2 - $amount1 / $amount1) / (($dayscount / 365) * 10000));
    $("#amount2").val($amount2);
    $("#amount3").val(parseFloat($amount2 - $amount1).toFixed(2));
    $("#amount4").val($apr);
    return [$amount1, $dayscount, $amount2, parseFloat($amount2 - $amount1).toFixed(2), $apr];
  }
  
  function addDaysToDate(days) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + (24 * days));

    var cStr = $.datepicker.formatDate("M d, yy", d);

    return cStr;
  }

  debugger;

  $("#slider1").slider({
    max: 5000,
    min: 500,
    step: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
      console.log(update());
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.value >= 2000) {
        $("#mindiv").show();
      } else {
        $("#mindiv").hide();
      }
    }
  });

  $("#slider2").slider({
    max: 30,
    min: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#days").val(ui.value);
      $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
      update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
    }
  });

  $("#days").val($("#slider2").slider("value"));

  $("#days").change(function(event) {
    var data = $("#days").val();
    if (data.length > 0) {
      if (parseInt(data) >= 0 && parseInt(data) <= 31) {
        $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", data);
      } else {
        if (parseInt(data) < 1) {
          $("#days").val("1");
          $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
        }
        if (parseInt(data) > 31) {
          $("#days").val("31");
          $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "31");
        }
      }
    } else {
      $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
    }
    $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
  });

  update();
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'> Loan Amount
<div id="slider1"></div>
Your Loan <input type="text" id="amount" value="500" /><br /><br /> hhhh
<div id="mindiv" style="display: none; background: red;">asds</div>
Loan Length
<div id="slider2"></div>
Days Loaned <input type="text" id="days" value="1" /><br /><br /> Repayment Date<br />
<div id="date"></div><br /> Your Loan
<input id="amount2" type="text" /> Interest
<input id="amount3" type="text" /><br /> APR
<input id="amount4" type="text" /><br />

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Sometimes it's better to put your functions first. Also it appears you were comparing against a value that would never be reached in Slider 1. I adjusted it and now when the amount is over 2000, the warning is shown. It will be shown after the slider is released. If you want to it appear during the slide action, move the actions to the `slide` callback.